# Использование массивов

Tags: массивы, php

Доброго времени суток.

Возник вопрос. Есть массив:

```
Array(
    [0]=>'<p class="1">1</p>',
    [1]=>'<p class="2">2</p>',
    [2]=>'<p class="3">3</p>',
    [3]=>'<p class="4">4</p>',
    [4]=>'<p class="5">5</p>',
    [5]=>'<p class="6">6</p>',
    [6]=>'<p class="7">7</p>',
    [7]=>'<p class="8">8</p>',
    [8]=>'<p class="9">9</p>',
    [9]=>'<p class="10">10</p>',
);
```

Надо массив разбить на части по 4 параграфа в каждой части. Т.е. чтобы по выходу получилось так:

```
<div class="part">
  <p class="1">1</p>
  <p class="2">2</p>
  <p class="3">3</p>
  <p class="4">4</p>
</div>
<div class="part">
  <p class="5">5</p>
  <p class="6">6</p>
  <p class="7">7</p>
  <p class="8">8</p>
</div>
<div class="part">
  <p class="9">9</p>
  <p class="10">10</p>
</div>
```

Уже голову сломал. Причем количество членов в массиве заранее не известно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

30 секунд на поиск документации

```
array_chunk($data, 4);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то мозг опух