# Вывод постов в wordpress

Tags: циклы, wordpress

Доброго времени суток.

Не подскажите, как организовать ввывод постов циклами по четыре поста, то есть чтобы в итоге получилось что-то вроде

```
<div class="part">
    //здесь должен начинаться цикл который выводить первые 4 поста
    <div class="post">
       //здесь тело первого поста
    </div>
    <div class="post">
       //здесь тело второго поста
    </div>
    <div class="post">
       //здесь тело третьего поста
    </div>
    <div class="post">
       //здесь тело четвертого поста
    </div>
</div>
//здесь первый цикл заканчиваеться и начинаеться второй
<div class="part">
    //здесь должен начинаться цикл который выводить первые 4 поста
    <div class="post">
       //здесь тело четвертого поста
    </div>
    <div class="post">
       //здесь тело пятого поста
    </div>
    <div class="post">
       //здесь тело шестого поста
    </div>
    <div class="post four">
       //здесь тело седьмого поста
    </div>
</div>
```

В рнр это можно сделать так: [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/386527/php-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2). А как это можно организовать в wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался очень прост, собствено, вот:

```
<?php
$count=0;?>
<div class="part">
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
     //здесь вывод контента
   <?php global $count;
    $count=$count+1;
    if ($count%4==0) {
    echo ('</div><div class="part">');
    };
endwhile; 
endif;
?>
```